# wp cron wordpress issue

Tags: wordpress, cron

In my wordpress website, I want to send a reminder every 30 days to the users that have not completed their profiles.
I started with making a simple example to test the cron, but it is not working. Can you please help me fix it?
The `SendEmailRemiderToESN` function is not working.

```
        // send reminder
    // Scheduled Action Hook
    function SendEmailRemiderToESN( ) {
        wp_mail( "sammoudi.maher@gmail.com","TestCron","Hello" );
    }
    add_action( 'SendEmailRemiderToESN', 'SendEmailRemiderToESN' );

    // Custom Cron Recurrences
    function custom_cron_job_recurrence( $schedules ) {
        $schedules['every30days'] = array(
            'display' => __( 'every30days', 'textdomain' ),
            'interval' => 2592000,
        );
        return $schedules;
    }
    add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'custom_cron_job_recurrence' );

    // Schedule Cron Job Event
    function custom_cron_job() {
        if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'SendEmailRemiderToESN' ) ) {
            wp_schedule_event( current_time( 'timestamp' ), 'every30days', 'SendEmailRemiderToESN' );
        }
    }
    add_action( 'wp', 'custom_cron_job' );
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you say "it is not working" please be specific about how it is not working and if you are getting any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Test this ;)
it's working in localhost on my mac

```
function custom_cron_job_recurrence_own( $schedules ) {

    $schedules['every30days'] = array(
        'interval'  => 2592000,
        'display'   => __( 'every30days', 'textdomain' )
    );

    return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'custom_cron_job_recurrence_own' );


if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'SendEmailRemiderToESN' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every30days', 'SendEmailRemiderToESN' );
}
add_action('SendEmailRemiderToESN', 'custom_cron_job_recurrence');

function custom_cron_job_recurrence() {

    wp_mail(................);

};
```

Comment: i think it is not working properly , because the custom_cron_job_recurrence() function is executing each time i reload the page however it should executed 1 time every 30 days .